# Could I please have my answers checked?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Thank you. I just need them checked.

[image: http://oi62.tinypic.com/5f5dmf.jpg]

[image: http://oi61.tinypic.com/28him2f.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

We disagree on the first problem.

The given triangle is isosceles so the base angles are congruent. This means that

$$2x-20=x+8.$$

Solving for $x$, we see that $x=28$. Thus both the base angles are $36^\circ$. The angle up top is then

$$
180 - 2 \cdot 36
$$

degrees.

---

The mistake you made with the first problem is you set the base angles equal and solved for $x$. Then you said that base angles are $x$ degrees. This however is not true. Once you solve for $x$ the base angles are, as given, $2x-20$ and $x+8$ degrees.

---

Your second answer is correct. The fact that $CD$ is perpendicular to $AB$ follows from [SSS](http://www.mathopenref.com/congruentsss.html).

Comment: Very good: I didn't even pay attention to the fact the congruent angles weren't $\;x^\circ\;$ but rather $\;(x+8)^\circ\;$...I suck and it's a great idea I'm not a junior high school teacher. +1